# Sharing data in the same database, being able to edit data

Tags: 7, views, database, external-scripts

I am looking for a way for Drupal to be able to access and modify data in an external table in the same database.

- Both Drupal and the script need access to the same data.
- Duplicating/Migrating is not an option since data should be available real time.
- Data is located in the same database, but the other script has its own tables.
- We currently use the Data module and Views to display data from the external tables, and that works well.
- We are having a hard time finding a way to add or edit records in these same tables within Drupal (i.e. Add/Edit/Delete forms within Drupal). We've found modules that read such data, but not write data.
- Ideally, the data in the external table should behave like an entity within Drupal. So, once defined and setup, it behaves just as if you were editing a node.
- Logged in Drupal users would have access to these forms to edit their own data (that actually resides in the other script's tables).
- Currently using Drupal 7 since it has more modules, but I am willing to upgrade to Drupal 8 if that's the only way to edit an external table within Drupal.

Comment: The Drupal way would be to create custom entity types and map them to your custom tables. That would take care of your penultimate 3 points

Comment: @Clive Are there any good tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: I don't know any off the top of my head, but the Examples module has a full custom entity in it, that might be a good place to start. If you get stuck at specific points just ask about them here

Comment: What's weird is that there is a module to view data in an external table, and there is even a module to import RSS feeds into an external table, but there are no modules (that I can find) that actually allow you to edit data in an external table.
Drupal <- external table = yes;
RSS -> Drupal -> external table = yes;
Drupal -> external table = no.

Comment: Perhaps this is not a common case. However creating such a module for one known table is not a big deal. It doesn't really matter where the table is situated. It could be even in external database.

Comment: Does the script only read data from the table or is it also adding/deleting/editing the data? Is the structure for the external table fixed or could you just create your custom entity and expose the data as feed to your external script?

Comment: There would need to be add/delete/update functionality, and the other script defines the database table, so no changes to the table structure are allowed, other than adding fields.